# Npm Including all range of pre-release when defining peer-dependency

Tags: npm, peer-dependencies

I am maintaining an NPM package (lets say it as `package-A`) that relies on an another NPM package(`package-B`) to function. Therefore, I am in need to add that package as peer-dependency into the `package.json`, so that npm and the user can be sure that everything is correct.

The problem is, `package-B` use pre-release versioning. I am well aware that it uses semver wrong, but I am not able to change the company policy, yet. Meanwhile enforcing to use proper versioning will happen. The semantic is like this:

- 1.0.1-alpha.X -> Unstable releases for testing and bleeding edge content
- 1.0.1-beta.X -> For every seemingly stable version (like rc)
- 1.0.2 -> When the package is production ready.

So basically, the patch version increases when there is another production release.

**Case:** Because of the versioning, I need to include every package except major one to match as peer dependency, together with pre-releases.

The need is basically `^1.0.0` with everything including pre-releases that happens to have `1` as major as peer dependency

- `^1.0.0` -> Does not include pre-releases
- `^1.0.0 || >=1.0.0-beta.X` -> Does not include e.g. `1.0.1-beta.1`
- `*` -> Does not include pre-releases
- `^1.0.0 || >=1.X.X-beta.X` -> Does not work.

On semver, there is a parameter called `--include-prerelease` which I think does what I need, specific to semver commands obviously.

`react` package on NPM has similar versioning system with proper usage of pre-release. E.g. it has `16.0.0`, `16.0.0-alpha.1` and `16.6.0-alpha.0`. I basically need to include all this on a single range.

**Disclaimer:** Minor version is changed when there is a breaking change going on. Yet again, I am **well aware** that this versioning is not up to semver regulations and advising it unfortunately will not solve the problem at hand.

Comment: > the patch version increases when there is another production release. 

the "pre-release" word and the semver 2.0 docs ([items 9 to 11](https://semver.org/#spec-item-9)), as well as [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngrx/component-store?activeTab=versions) big package's releases, all lead me to believe the order of released versions should be 1.0.1-alpha.X -> 1.0.1-beta.X -> 1.0.1, because it would mean that the alpha and beta are candidates for the 1.0.1 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-versions#toc-pre-release-tags

> If a comparator includes a version with a pre-release tag it will only match against versions that have the same `major.minor.patch` version.

You can only include pre-releases of specific versions.

`>=1.0.0-beta` includes `1.0.0-beta.X`, but not `1.0.1-beta.X`

You can play around with the semver pre-release ranges on https://semver.npmjs.com/
Lookup the package `@artsy/reaction` they have bunch of pre-releases

Comment: Thanks, I can safely assume that it isn't possible to accomplish this feat. That's a bummer.

Comment: You'd have to specify every version. It can be done like `^1.0.0-beta || ^1.0.1-beta` etc. It's possible, but not practical.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this applicable to this use case, but in situations where I wanted a peer dependency to accept any prerelease, I've done something like:

```json
"peerDependency": {
  "depName": "^1.0.0-0"
}
```

I'm not sure of the exact term for the trailing `-0` of the semver, but I've considered it a wildcard, of sorts.

---

EDIT: To provide some more context. My experience is limited to doing this with NPM, but I would hope how various package managers handle semantic versioning would be the same. In the case of `npm`, it uses the `semver` module for evaluating semantic versions. Here's an rough example of how I *think* `npm` evaluates prerelease versions.

```
import semver from 'semver';

const accepted = '^1.0.0-0';
const prereleases = [
  '1.0.1-alpha.0',
  '1.0.6-beta.0',
  '1.0.6-next.0',
  '1.3.0-0.64-34-aerf3asdf33'
];

for(const prerelease of prereleases) {
  const satisified = semver.satisfies(prerelease, accepted, { includePrerelease: true });
  console.log('satisified', prerelease, satisified);
}
```

Comment: Hmm so does it accept all there is for prerelease tags? I will try this and if it works, I'd like to update all the packages with this ruleset.

Comment: I believe it does. I've only dealt with this in the context of NPM, but in that case, it uses the `semver` module to determine if a version matches the provided semantic versioning. I'll update my answer with a code snippet to show how you can test against that module.

Comment: THanks again for your feedback. I was going to test this but for some reason, it accepts both prereleased versions and normal versions even thou I only include normal versions, therefore I couldn't reproduce the problem. I will try again later when I have to fiddle with the packages next.